# Angularjs add a Child Object to Json Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, addchild

When I try to add the Children to `Json` Object 
i am getting an issue :

> TypeError: ctrl.otsact.tests.push is not a function

Script :

```
function addOTSACT() {
        var data = {
            'date': '',
            'subjects': angular.copy(ctrl.otsactSubjectsCopy)
        }
        $('.dateField').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        });
        ctrl.otsact.tests.push({});
    }
```

Json Object :

```
{  
   "ACT":{  
      "name":"ACT",
      "tests":{  
         "73":{  
            "id":73,
            "official_test_id":1,
            "student_id":165888,
            "test_date":"2017-05-12",
            "score":"0.0",
            "created_at":"2017-05-23 13:50:40",
            "created_by_id":2766,
            "updated_at":"2017-05-23 13:50:40",
            "updated_by_id":2766,
            "subjects":[  
               {  
                  "id":1,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":1,
                  "score":1,
                  "student_score_id":73,
                  "name":"English",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":2,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":2,
                  "score":1,
                  "student_score_id":73,
                  "name":"Math",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":3,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":3,
                  "score":1,
                  "student_score_id":73,
                  "name":"Reading",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":4,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":4,
                  "score":1,
                  "student_score_id":73,
                  "name":"Science",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":5,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":5,
                  "score":1,
                  "student_score_id":73,
                  "name":"Writing",
                  "is_consider":0
               }
            ]
         },
         "74":{  
            "id":74,
            "official_test_id":1,
            "student_id":165888,
            "test_date":"2017-05-12",
            "score":"0.0",
            "created_at":"2017-05-23 13:50:40",
            "created_by_id":2766,
            "updated_at":"2017-05-23 13:50:40",
            "updated_by_id":2766,
            "subjects":[  
               {  
                  "id":1,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":1,
                  "score":2,
                  "student_score_id":74,
                  "name":"English",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":2,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":2,
                  "score":2,
                  "student_score_id":74,
                  "name":"Math",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":3,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":3,
                  "score":2,
                  "student_score_id":74,
                  "name":"Reading",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":4,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":4,
                  "score":2,
                  "student_score_id":74,
                  "name":"Science",
                  "is_consider":1
               },
               {  
                  "id":5,
                  "official_test_id":1,
                  "student_id":165888,
                  "official_test_subject_id":5,
                  "score":2,
                  "student_score_id":74,
                  "name":"Writing",
                  "is_consider":0
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i want to add 75 children to test children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON tests is not an array but an object, and you cannot push to an object. So this line is wrong:

```
ctrl.otsact.tests.push({});
```

You have to change it to:

```
ctrl.otsact.tests[MYNEWID] = MYNEWOBJECT;
```

Comment: then. to remove the object i am getting a similar issue. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203137/angularjs-remove-a-child-object-from-json-object?noredirect=1#comment75419848_44203137)

Comment: answered there in the question, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Your `tests` property is...an `object`, not an `array`. Tests should be `tests: []`, not `tests: {}`.